# Set the `class` attribute of a dynamically-created element in JavaScript

Tags: html, css, custom-element

I have a custom element, which is created like:

```
connectedCallback()
{
  var on_off_switch = document.createElement('Div');
  on_off_switch.class = 'switch demo3';

  this.appendChild(on_off_switch);

 }
```

But I noticed when viewing the source that the `on_off_switch`'s class is not set to `switch demo3`.

All other assignments work, like `on_off_switch.style['background-color'] = 'red'`, etc.

Is it possible to set the CSS `class` of a element appended inside a custom element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For [historical reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className#Notes), the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property is used instead of `class`:

```js
function connectedCallback () {
  var on_off_switch = document.createElement('div')
  on_off_switch.className = 'switch demo3'

  this.appendChild(on_off_switch)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`class` is the name of the element **attribute**, while `className` is its corresponding **property**:

```
on_off_switch.className = 'switch demo3'
// or    
on_off_switch.setAttribute('class', 'switch demo3')
```